# get and write to json document in a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

Heres my js file

```
var records = [
  {
    id: 1,
    username: process.env.USER1,
    password: process.env.USER1PASSWORD,
    displayName: "LilNelly",
    emails: [{ value: "lurey@madison.k12.wi.us" }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    username: process.env.USER2,
    password: process.env.USER2PASSWORD,
    displayName: "Guest" + Date.now().toString(),
    emails: [{ value: "123@gmail.com" }]
  }
];
```

Im trying to add to this array called records by using fs

But fs only appends to the file im trying to append a document in a specific place not on top of the file. Hopefully u understand. also im using js as the file not json.

Comment: read the file contents to a string, append where you want, replace the content with new string

Comment: you can try it like this:

2 files:
js_part1.js
js_part2.js

then append your var to js_part1.js
then append js_part2.js to js_part1.js